# Scala: equivalent of np.digitize to bucketize data

Tags: java, python, scala, numpy, bucket

With scala I have some data, for ex.

```
val values = Seq(0, 2, 10, 50)
```

And I defined buckets, eg.

```
val buckets = TreeMap[Int, Double]((0, -0.001),
                                   (1, 1.5),
                                   (2, 5),
                                   (3, 20)
```

Then I want, from my values, to have the buckets indexes, eg.

```
val result = Seq(0, 1, 2, 3)
```

In python this can be done with np.digitize, in scala I can't find an equivalent with Nd4j or Breeze.

Is there an optimized solution to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you are using an older Breeze version. If you include:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.scalanlp" %% "breeze" % "0.13.2"
```

in your .sbt file you can use that function. For example:

```
import breeze.stats._

val arr1 = Array(-3, 0.5, 1, 1.5, 4)
val arr2 = Array(0, 1, 2)

digitize(arr1, arr2)
```

It gives

```
Array(0, 1, 1, 2, 3)
```

Comment: I don't understand why there is no documentation about it, anyway this is exactly what I was looking for thx!

Comment: Yes, maybe we should update the wiki with more examples like this